# Internal messages between users of a ROR3 website: ready components?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Developing a new ROR3 website, I need to implement a sort of internal mail system:

- user1 sends a message to user2
- user2 receives a real-world email and can also see the message in his "Inbox" on the website.
- user1 sees the message in his "Sent mail" folder.

Many websites have this feature.
Is there a Ruby on Rails module to add this feature with minimal development/maintenance?

*Note: Simple messages (title and body, plain text) is good enough*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straight forward to implement on your own.

Create a Message model like this

```
Message
  fromUserId
  toUserId
  title
  body
  is_read
  created_at
```

And when a message is created you can just create an email copy that you automatically send to toUserId.

Comment: Im interested in doing sometthting like this but i dont know how to go about it